# stop page from showing up when making get request without redirect using curl

Tags: php, curl, get, request

My goal is to make a get request to a specified `url` without a redirect and without a visual difference in the website. I want to make a get request like `<img src="http://www.google">` does, which is without a redirect, silent in the background and without a visual difference in the page it is executed on.
Here is my code:

```
$curl_handle = curl_init();
curl_setopt( $curl_handle, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://www.google.com' );
curl_setopt( $curl_handle, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 0);
curl_exec( $curl_handle );
curl_close( $curl_handle );
```

Now the problem with the above `php` code is that when it is run, the main page of http://www.google.com is loaded onto the page similar to an `iframe`. So my question is, how can i stop that from happening? How can i make the get request without any visual difference just like `<img src="http://www.google.com">` does?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER` option to get content of requested URL instead of printing it to web page.

```
$curl_handle = curl_init();
curl_setopt( $curl_handle, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://www.google.com' );
curl_setopt( $curl_handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt( $curl_handle, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 0);
curl_exec( $curl_handle );
curl_close( $curl_handle );
```